# Prevent C# events to VB6 code to create a dead lock

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, vb6

I created a multithreading C# COM-Assembly, I used it from VB6.

The C#-COM can fire events from multiple threads, I created an invisible From-object and use this to synchronize all events before raise them.

```
if (myForm.InvokeRequired() )
{
  delOnMessage myDelegate = new delOnMessage(Message_received);
  myForm.Invoke(myDelegate, new object[] { null, null });
}
else
{
  RaiseMyEvent();
}
```

But if the VB6-Code is inside of an event handler and calls some methods of the COM-Object, this can produce a new event.

```
Private Sub m_SomeClass_SomeEvent(obj As Variant)
    COMobject.SendAnAnswer() ' This produces a new event
End Sub
```

In that case a part of the event-system stops working, suprisingly the Main VB6 Applikation still works.

**EDIT: More detailed**
If the C#-COM received a Message (from CAN-Bus-Thread) it creates an event, in some cases the VB6 calls a C#-COM method which creates an event, this event is reached the VB6 too.
But then the CAN-Bus-Thread seems to be blocked, as no more messages are received (till program restart).
But other events can occur.

The CAN-Bus-Thread is an endless loop to receive a message and fire an event.

I have two questions:

**Is my way of synchronizing correct?**
**Is it possible without modifying the VB6-code to get it working?**

Comment: What does "part of the event-system stops working" mean, exactly?  Are the C# threads crashing, blocking forever, something else?  I assume at least the C# form was created on the VB6 main thread?  (As an aside, usually just creating an instance of Control will suffice for Invoke instead of a full-blown form).

Comment: Thanks for the instance of _Control will suffice_ tip. I'm edited the question for make the "part of the event-system stops working" more clear

Comment: Does the CAN-Bus thread block on the message recv or the event dispatch?  When it is blocked, can you look at the call stack and see if a prior Control.Invoke is on the stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I created an invisible From-object

That sounds like trouble.  Using InvokeRequired is a dangerous anti-pattern.  It is especially lethal with VB6, its runtime has badly broken thread handling.  You *know* that the code is being called from a worker thread, use InvokeRequired only to verify that the form you use to synchronize is in the proper state to do so correctly:

```
if (!myForm.InvokeRequired()) {
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Synchronization window not created");
}
delOnMessage myDelegate = new delOnMessage(FireMessageReceivedEvent);
myForm.BeginInvoke(myDelegate, new object[] { null, null });
```

Odds are good that this exception will throw, creating an invisible form is not that easy.  You can force the form's Handle property to be created by reading its Handle property.  Or by overriding its SetVisibleCore() method to keep the form invisible:

```
    protected override void SetVisibleCore(bool value) {
        if (!this.IsHandleCreated) {
            this.CreateHandle();
            value = false;
        }
        base.SetVisibleCore(value);
    }
```

It is however *very* important that you call this form's Show() method on the main thread.  It still won't work correctly if you create the form in your worker thread.  There's no easy way to check for this in your code.  Use the debugger and the Debug + Windows + Threads window to verify this.

Last but not least, do favor BeginInvoke() instead of Invoke().  This has much smaller odds of creating deadlock.  This can cause problems by itself however, your worker thread may need to be throttled to prevent it flooding the main thread with invoke requests.

Comment: I create my invisible DebugForm by `public class DebugForm : Form { public DebugForm(bool visible) { InitializeComponent(); this.Visible = visible; }` at program start it is visible for a short time, this worked the last years. Why it should make a difference in which thread I create it?

Comment: Because it will marshal the call to the wrong thread.  It has to be the VB6 main thread or it will malfunction.

Comment: Fortunately the form is created in the VB6-thread context. Btw. I can't use `BeginInvoke()` as it's necessary for VB6 (and my own event handlers) to be synchron, to be in a defined state in the moment of the event handler is executed

Comment: _Using InvokeRequired is a dangerous anti-pattern._ but what would be the correct pattern here?

Comment: It is in my post, use InvokeRequired to verify that the window is ready to do the marshaling.

Comment: I wouldn't say that the VB6 "runtime has badly broken thread handling", it just isn't designed for free threading.

Comment: What did, free threading?  Guess I never tried bending VB quite that far :)

Comment: @Hans Passant: But using InvokeRequired that way isn't a solution, most of the time I would throw exceptions instead of events

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the nature of the event, it may be sufficient simply to switch from `Invoke` to `BeginInvoke`, so that it is offloaded to the message-queue (without blocking, so no deadlock). It is convenient that `Control.BeginInvoke` (unlike `Delegate.BeginInvoke`) does **not** require you to call `EndInvoke`, so you can use this in a fire-and-forget way.

I *might* be tempted to cut out some extra work, though:

```
myForm.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)RaiseMyEvent);
```

(i.e. jump direct to `RaiseMyEvent`)

Comment: It's necessary that the events are executed synchronized, to get a defined behaviour, so I can only use `Invoke`